# Flex Alchemy: Returning a ByteArray from C function

Tags: c, apache-flex, arrays, alchemy

I am using Flex's Alchemy library to generate SWC's out of C files. I have a byte array (`unsigned char buffer[size]`) in the c-layer that I'd like to return to the ActionScript layer as a `ByteArray`. Do I have to iterate through the array and explicitly call `AS3_Set` on each element or is there a way to just return the entire C array at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished by using the [AS3_ByteArray_writeBytes](http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Alchemy:Documentation:Developing_with_Alchemy:C_API#int_AS3_ByteArray_writeBytes.28AS3_Val_dst.2C_void_.2Asrc.2C_int_len.29) function of the Alchemy API.

Answer (score 0):

In C, when returning from the function called by Flash, return the pointer to the C-array, like this:

```
int * myArray = malloc(100);
//populate array...
return AS3_Array("IntType", (int)myArray);
```

Then, in Flash:

```
import cmodule.<c module name>.MemUser;
...
memory = new MemUser();
for (var i:int = 0; i<4;i++) { //getting a 4 uints array
    trace(memory._mru16(data[0] + i*4)); //data is the return value from C
}
```

Or use [these functions](http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Alchemy%3aDocumentation%3aDeveloping_with_Alchemy%3aAS3_API#MemUser) to read the ints/floats/char from the c-array (you can't just use ByteArray.readInt(), the numbers in c are represented differently)

Comment: Why not just return an AS3_Int( (int)myArray ) in the C code?